# MyPy Missing return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am having an issue with mypy tossing an error saying I'm missing a return statement. While I have one in the function, it still proceeds to exist. Am I doing something wrong?

(I am using python3.8)

```
def misc_menu_choice(misc_menu_input: str) -> str:
    """Provides mapping for the misc_menu"""
    try:
        if misc_menu_input == '1':
            list_all()
        if misc_menu_input == '2':
            intermarriages()
        elif misc_menu_input == '3':
            toggle_program()
            toggle_living_only()

        elif misc_menu_input == '4':

            selection = get_user_input(main_menu())
            main_menu_selection(selection)
        elif misc_menu_input == '':

            print(f'Current ID: {current_person}\t\t\
Living Only: {program_status}')
            miscellanious_menu_prompt()

        else:

            print('Please select again')
            miscellanious_menu_prompt()
        return misc_menu_input

    except ValueError:
        print("That is not an option")
        miscellanious_menu_prompt()
```

Comment: You don't return anything after you catch an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You've annotated your function signature like so:

```
def misc_menu_choice(misc_menu_input: str) -> str: ...
```

Your annotation states that your function accepts a single argument, `misc_menu_input`, a string, and returns a string. However, this is not what your function does.

If there is no `ValueError` inside the `try` clause, your function adheres to the annotation you've given it, and returns a string. However, if there is a `ValueError` inside the `try` clause, the rest of the `try` clause is skipped, and the `except` clause is executed. There is no `return` statement in the `except` clause, meaning that if there is a `ValueError` leading to the `except` clause being executed, your function will return `None`, contradicting the annotation you have given it.

Comment: So how should the function be annotated? Since it can return a str or a ValueError, which one would be correct for the function? @alex-waygood

Comment: @FranciscoPérez, it doesn't "return" `ValueError`. In the event that you reach the `except ValueError` block, the function implicitly returns `None`, as there is no `return` statement in the `except ValueError` block. If this is the intended behaviour of the function, then you should put an explicit `return None` at the end of the `except ValueError` block, and change the return annotation to `Union[str, None]` to indicate that it sometimes returns `str`, and sometimes `None`. But I doubt that this is really the intended behaviour of the function.